# > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0]

Tags: flutter, dart, androidx

After installing location_permissions package I hade to migrate my flutter app to androidx,
I followed the instructions, But now whenever I run my app I get the following error:

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Saad\AndroidStudioProjects\falafeelo\android\build.gradle' line: 36
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0] on object
of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log
output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 58s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using
Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.**

this is my android\build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
}
```

app\build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the                     
local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
   (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.saad2002.falafeelo"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
    // Read the API key from ./secure.properties into R.string.maps_api_key
    def secureProps = new Properties()
    if (file("../secure.properties").exists()) {
        file("../secure.properties")?.withInputStream { secureProps.load(it) }
    }
    resValue "string", "maps_api_key", (secureProps.getProperty("MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")

    }

    buildTypes {    
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    }
    }

   flutter {
   source '../..'
   }

   dependencies {
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   //    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
   //    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move this to app/build.gradle instead of android/build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
}
```

So it should look like this at the end of android/build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   //    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
   //    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'

   }
```

Comment: I tried that but now im getting this error:_> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':cloud_firestore:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not download lint-checks-27.0.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:27.0.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/27.0.2/lint-checks-27.0.2.jar'.
         > Connection reset  > Could not download lint-api-27.0.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:27.0.2)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/27.0.2/lint-api-27.0.2...